# C# Chart видимое построение

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Как сделать что бы было видно как в chart строится график?

```
chart.Update()
```

Работает слишком медленно

Comment: На самом деле Вы задали очень общий вопрос, поэтому напишу Вам в комментарии. Первая ссылка, которая будет интересна Вам: [Chart Control Animation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument115787). Ну и для полноты ответа дам совет: чтобы построить анимированный график - Вам необходимо заполнить список точек графика `List<PointF>`. А затем, используя простой таймер `Timer` отображать подготовленные данные с помощью `Timer.Tick` события. В таймере выставить интервал и не забыть его остановить в конце. Был бы вопрос более конкретным - был бы и ответ :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"медленно" - субъективное понятие. Возможно, Windows Forms и не сможет обеспечить нужную вам скорость обновления.

Тем не менее, вы можете попробовать сделать следующее:

- Установить у Chart свойство DoubleBuffered в true
- Когда вы обновляете данные графика, вызвать метод Refresh

Comment: DoubleBuffered  не нашел у Chart

Comment: Свойство  [DoubleBuffered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx) есть у любого элемента управления Windows Forms. Если свойство не видно в конструкторе форм, его можно установить в коде.